# SQL conditional statement to include operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am passing parameters into a stored procedure. The one parameter is a `varchar(50)` that can be a string like `" > 5000"` and `" <= 10000"`.

Here is some of the code:

```
....
....
@colourid int = 0,
@regionid int = 0,
@sellingPrice varchar(50) = '-1'
AS
SELECT
....
....
WHERE
(dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_ColourID = CASE WHEN @colourid = 0 THEN dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_ColourID ELSE @colourid END)
AND (dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_RegionID = CASE WHEN @regionid = 0 THEN dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_RegionID ELSE @regionid END)
AND
```

How do I add `@sellingPrice` to the WHERE? I can't mimic how it was done for the int parameters because it's not always going to use `=`. I need to say "if selling price is not -1 then fld_SellingPrice @sellingPrice".

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can achieve that is by using dynamic SQL, building up your query in a local variable and then executing it via (preferably) `sp_executesql`.

So something like

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT .... WHERE ' + @sellingPrice

sp_executesql @sql
```

However, this really does open you up to the possibility of SQL injection, and therefore you have to either

a. Be very sure that the procedure will only be called by callers you trust fully
b. Add protection for badly formed parameters within your procedure, which is much harder than it sounds
c. Find a different way to approach the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you are going to have a general set of comparisons to use, I would create a parameter per comparison in your SP and use them as needed.  So your SP might have

```
 @greaterThan int,
 @lessThan int,
 @equalTo int
```

Then in the SP you could do

```
if @greaterThan IS NULL
    SELECT @greaterThan = MAX(field) FROM table -- or some arbitrary value that will always evaluate to true
if @lessThan IS NULL
    SELECT @lessThan = MIN(field) FROM table
```

Then just use those in your WHERE clause.  Otherwise, as posted, you're going to have to do dynamic SQL by building an SQL string with the pieces of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a from and a to variable.
So when you want less than 5000, you set to variable = 5000 and leave from blank

```
....
....
@colourid int = 0,
@regionid int = 0,
@fromsellingprice int = 5000
@tosellingprice int = null
AS
SELECT
....
....
WHERE
(dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_ColourID = CASE WHEN @colourid = 0 THEN dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_ColourID ELSE @colourid END)
AND (dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_RegionID = CASE WHEN @regionid = 0 THEN dbo.tbl_Listings.fld_RegionID ELSE @regionid END)
AND
sellingPrice >= coalesce(@fromsellingprice, sellingprice)
and sellingPrice <= coalesce(@tosellingprice, sellingprice)
```

Comment: +1, alternatively: `sellingPrice BETWEEN coalesce(@fromsellingprice, sellingprice) AND coalesce(@tosellingprice, sellingprice)`

Comment: @AndriyM yes, same thing. idea was to avoid dynamic sql and give a better alternative to passing a conditional varchar like '< 5000', which is an invitation to problems future problems. I guess that is why you upvoted me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly in SQL - the parameter will not be parsed and interpreted as part of the query with predicates.

The only way to do this (passing in the operator) is to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), which comes with its own pitfalls.

You may consider passing in a parameter for what operator to use and have a bunch of `if` sections for each supported parameter - this may be worse than dynamic SQL.